# Collision detection, without the physics?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have enemies following a path in my game. Along the path I have turrets shooting at them. To get collision detection between the bullet of the turret and enemy i've added RigidBody2D, and Circle Collider 2D to the enemy, and Circle Collider 2D to the bullet.

When the bullet hits the enemy it shall not push the object, just destroy the bullet and take some of the health.

I feel Rigidbody2D is messing it up, it gives mass, drag and gravity to my enemy... but I dont need it. But it seems I do if I want to have collision detection bewteen two objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Rigidbody to detect collisions, however you are just triggering some actions (taking damage). That is why you can check `isTrigger` on your colliders, and then implement 'OnTriggerEnter2D' callback instead of 'OnCollisionEnter2D', which won't activate any physics.

See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html for reference.